# If the $k^{th}$ derivative of a polynomial $f$ has exactly $r$ zeroes in $[a,b]$, then, number of zeroes of $f$ in $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If the $k^{th}$ derivative of a polynomial $f$ has exactly $r$ zeroes in $[a,b]$, what can you conclude about the number of zeroes of $f$ in $[a,b]$?

**Attempt:** (I came across this question in a chapter devoted to Rolle's Theorem.)

$f^{(k)}(x)= (x-a)^r g(x)$ such that $(x-a)$ does not divide $g(x)$.

Rolle's Theorem states that any real-valued differentiable function that attains equal values at two distinct points must have a stationary point somewhere between them—that is, a point where the first derivative (the slope of the tangent line to the graph of the function) is zero.

The converse might not be true?

But the problem asks me to go backward. So, we can't use rolle's theorem right?

Could you please tell me how to move forward?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't see how you should be able to conclude anything. The $k$'th derivative of $f$ and $f+1$ is the same, but $f$ and $f+1$ are quite likely to have different amounts of zeroes in $[a,b]$.

Comment: I understand and I was thinking the same. Saw this problem in Calculus by Apostol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u$ be the number of zeros of the original function $f(x)$.

Rolle's theorem tells us that the number of zeros of $f'(x)$ is at least $u-1$.
 The number of zeros of $f''(x)$ is at least $u-2$ etc. So, the $k$-th derivate
 has at least $u-k$ zeros. So, $u-k\le r$, so $u\le k+r$. So, the original
 funtion has at most $k+r$ distinct roots.

Comment: Uhm, I got some confusion here please. The converse of Rolle's theorem may not be true right?

Comment: If we have $u$ distinct roots, then there are $u-1$ intervals, in which the derivate must be $0$, so the derivate must have at leat $u-1$ roots.

Comment: but if the derivative has at leat u−1 roots, it doesn't mean thatwe have u distinct roots

Comment: You are right, that the converse of rolle's theorem is false, but I did not use the converse.

Comment: I could transform my proof also in a contradiction-proof. If the original function would have more than $k+r$ roots, the $k$-th derivate would have more than $r$ roots, contradicing the assumption.

Comment: Let us take $f(x)= x^4+x^2+1. f(x) $ has no real roots. Hence, $u=0$. Then $f '(x)$ must have $u-1=-1$ zeroes (!) ? However, $f'(x) = 4x^3+2x+1$ definitely has $1$ real root.

Comment: No, not $u-1$ zeros, AT LEAST $u-1$ zeros. $1$ zeros does not contradict "at least (-1) zeros".

Comment: oh okay :) . That's where, I guess, I was faltering

Comment: Thank you for your answer.